# Make <div> tag(s) fill parent <td>

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is filled dynamically. Each `<td>` could have one or more `<div class="{success,failure}Status">` inside of it. Those status divs are colored green or red based on success or failure.

I want those divs to completely fill the parent `<td>`. Originally, I was using `height: 100%;`, but if there are multiple divs, then this is not good. However, if I remove the height selector, the entries with only one `<div>` are puny. This is seen in the picture below.

How can I ensure that these single `<td>` entries with only a single `<div>` are completely filled?

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates my point:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.successDiv {
  background-color: green;
}

.failureDiv {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>
      Components
    </td>
      <td>
        Step 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Step 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Step 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Name
    </td>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
          <div class="failureDiv">
            Failure
          </div>
      </td>
    <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
          <div class="failureDiv">
            Failure
          </div>
          <div class="failureDiv">
            Failure
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this snippet, the single green success div should fill its parent td. This should not affect the thead or the first td in each row; those are headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:only-child` like this.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.successDiv {
  background-color: green;
}

.failureDiv {
  background-color: red;
}

.successDiv, .failureDiv {
   height: 30px;
 }

.successDiv:only-child, .failureDiv:only-child {
   height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>
      Components
    </td>
      <td>
        Step 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Step 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Name
    </td>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="successDiv">
            Success
          </div>
          <div class="failureDiv">
            Failure
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That looks great, but what if there is a td with two divs and another with three divs? That fixes the problem if there is one, but not if there are two. I edited my code snippet to include that case.

Comment: On second thought, that's probably pretty complex. There will be different proportions and whatnot. This should be sufficient. Thanks so much for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.successDiv {
  background-color: green;
}
.failureDiv {
  background-color: red;
}
.successDiv:only-child,
.failureDiv:only-child {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Components
      </td>
      <td>
        Step 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Step 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Name
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="successDiv">
        Success
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="successDiv">
        Success
      </div>
      <div class="failureDiv">
        Failure
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```